# Chrome execCommand('insertHTML') behavior

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, execcommand

While developing some kind of WYSIWYG-editor with not editable blocks, i found intresting behavior in Chrome (and Safari also): when you make an execCommand('insertHTML') in `div` with `contenteditable="true"` (or another element) - in work fine, like you expect. But if you try to execute it in nested `div` without "`contenteditable`" - browser remove all attributes, but add `style` according to css.

jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/DXz9e/2/

Try to insert in inner and outer text. And look at html-code. I see in outer (with contenteditable):

```
<span id="newInsertedNode" class="constructor-input-field" data-id="23">Some text</span>
```

And in inner:

```
<span style="background-color: red; color: blue;">Some text</span>
```

I just want to say: "what a hell is going on?"
Also it work fine in FF

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to not use a Span element (see here: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9004).